# seaborn: despine plots by default

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

```
matplotlib.pyplot.figure()
....
seaborn.despine(offset=10)
```

The `despine` function of seaborn offsets the axis spines from the plot, which looks quite nice. The function needs to be called after the code that plots a figure. However, I would like this to be the default for any plot, at least any seaborn plot. How can this be configured?

Alternatively, how can this be made part of a plotting context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matplotlib added rc params to control spine visibility in version 1.5, so you could turn off the visibility of the top and right spines by default with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc("axes.spines", top=False, right=False)
```

However, matplotlib does not expose spine offsets through the rc params, so there is no setting that will automatically apply those to every plot.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I assume http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.plotting_context.html doesn't enable this either.

Comment: A) No, the seaborn modifications to defaults are entirely dependent on what parameters the matplotlib rc machinery exposes and B) No, the plotting context is only concerned with changing the scales of plot elements; the aesthetic appearance of the plot is controlled by `seaborn.axes_style`.